# Angularjs/Restangular, how to name file blob for download?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

For some reason this seems easier in IE than Chrome/FF:

```
$scope.download = function() {
    Restangular.one(myAPI)
      .withHttpConfig({responseType: 'blob'}).customGET().then(function(response) {

        //IE10 opens save/open dialog with filename.zip
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(response, 'filename.zip');

        //Chrome/FF downloads a file with random name                
        var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(response);
        window.location.href = url;
    });
};
```

Is there a way to do something similar to how IE10+ works? That is, I can specify a file name/type (will only be zip)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As soon as you have your object url you can create an anchor and set the [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) attribute to the filename you want, set the href to the object url, and then just call click

```js
var myBlob = new Blob(["example"],{type:'text/html'})
var blobURL = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(myBlob);
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
anchor.download = "myfile.txt";
anchor.href = blobURL;
anchor.click();
```

[Download attribute compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)

Comment: Is it possible to change the file name without using `<a>` tag? I'm gonna build the angular to mobile, and creating `<a>` tag didn't help out downloading the file

Answer (score 1):

Just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-saver
Browser Support table can be seen here: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/